# Is it possible to use both the Android Eclipse plugin and the Android command-line tools on a single project?

Tags: android, eclipse, command-line, development-environment

I'm on a team with some members who like to the use the Android Eclipse plugin and some who like to use other editors and therefore use the Android command-line tools.  We're about to start a project with members from both camps, so I'm wondering if it is possible to use both the Eclipse plugin and the command-line tools at the same time so that everyone can work in their preferred environment.

Personally, I've been using VIM and the command-line tools for Android development so far.  I had a look at the Eclipse plugin to see if interoperability with the command-line tools would be possible, but it seems that the plugin does not generate any of the Ant build files that the command-line tools use.  Is there some way to make the Eclipse plugin generate these files?

Answer (score 1):

That shouldnt be a problem...

Eclipse builds the app and produces a .apk file like on the fly where if you want to use the command line you have to follow a different procedure..

Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/index.html
and in particular

"if you are developing in a non-Eclipse environment, you can build your project with the generated build.xml Ant file that is in the project directory. The Ant file calls targets that automatically call the build tools for you."

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I hadn't seen this part of the docs before.

If my understanding is correct, there shouldn't be any theoretical barrier to using both Eclipse and the command-line tools on the same project, since they both effectively do the same thing.  Now I need to figure out if it's possible for the Eclipse project files and the command-line tools configuration files (e.g. Ant files) to co-exist in the same project (my guess is that this shouldn't be a problem).  I also need to figure out a good way to keep any custom build steps synchronized between the two sets of tools.

Comment: @Nathan If everyone is using his own pc then you can set up a repository..that way everyone gets to build and run the way he/she likes...just a suggestion...